# Se corta texto al asignarlo al input por javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Ayuda con javascript.... hola a todos.. tengo una funcion que recibe un parametro de tipo texto "EAGLE PASS, TX", y llega bien a la funcion, lo verifique con un ALERT... el problema es que estoy agregando dinamicamente un input al html y al asignar el valor me lo corta, solo muestra EAGLE y si mando LAREDO, TX, lo corta en la coma.....

```
html_code += '<input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad' + '" value=' + ciudad + ' class="form-control" />';
$('#lineasDetalleRuta').append(html_code);
```

Comment: Por qué concatenas `+ '" value=' + ciudad + '` sólo tendría que ser así `html_code += '<input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad"  value="' + ciudad + '" class="form-control" />';` intenta cambiar eso,aunque no creo que sea por eso.

Comment: Hola amigo.. listo...  tienes razon en lo de la concatenacion.. pero ademas habia dejado   value=' + ciudad + '    cuando debia ser     value="' + ciudad + '"    como tu me comentaste.. graciass

Comment: Pues así te comente en el ejemplo de abajo, te la dejo como respuesta.

Comment: Asi es amigo.. gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: No pongas SOLUCIONADO al título de tu pregunta, eso no es válido; en cambio marca como aceptada la respuesta que te solucionó el problema

Comment: Ah ok... soy nuevo en estos menesteres.. gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu tienes esta concatenación, no es necesario concatenar el `value` solamente la variable JS

```
  html_code += '<input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad' + '" value=' + ciudad + ' class="form-control" />';
```

De esta forma funcionaría:

```
html_code += '<input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" value="' + ciudad + '" class="form-control" />';
```

O puedes hacer el uso de [templates strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) que se me hace una forma más cómoda

```
html_code += `<input type="text" name="ciudad" id="ciudad" value="${ciudad}" class="form-control" />`;
```

Comment: gracias por tu ayuda

Comment: @LeonardoVelazquez, En mi respuesta en la parte superior izquierda esta un símbolo de paloma o de check, dale click eso hará que cambie de color a verde, significa que haz aceptado mi respuesta como válida.

Comment: @VickMuñoz para tu último ejemplo donde hablas de **template strings** me parece que las comillas que debes usar son las backticks o comillas invertidas: **``**

Comment: Si, se me pasó por alto, ya modifico, gracias.